# UIPickerView UIScrolling with view

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, xcode4.6

I have a `UIPickerView` on a scrollable view with multiple buttons and textfields. `UIPickerView` picks values into two of the text fields. Now, the problem is `UIPickerView` is also scrolling along with the page. Can any one guide me how to keep the `UIPickerView` at the bottom and opaque on a scrollable page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `UIPickerView` to the superview of the `UIScrollView` (possibly the `view` property of the `UIViewController` that you're working in.

You might also want to extend the `contentSize` property of the scroll view by the height of the picker view so that all objects in the scroll view can be scrolled on screen and aren't hidden under the picker view.

Answer (score 0):

Take another View on the top of the scroll view and put your UIPickerView into that so it is now independent to your UIScrollView like this:

[image]